# How can I update row indexes in an HTML table after hiding or deleting rows?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, html-table

I have a table and I need to delete rows and update the first column with index.

The delete function works but I don't have an idea how to update the first column. Do I need to use a `for` loop?

This is what I've done so far:

```js
const deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');

for (i = 0; i < deleteButtons.length; i++) {
  deleteButtons[i].addEventListener('click', ({ currentTarget }) => {
    currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Duration</th>
      <th scope="col">Play</th>
      <th scope="col">Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Didn't love</td>
      <td>4:18</td>
      <td><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa love">&#xf144;</i></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o delete" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>                           </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Keys</td>
      <td>3:51</td>
      <td><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa keys">&#xf144;</i></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o delete" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Smoking</td>
      <td>5:12</td>
      <td><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa smoking">&#xf144;</i></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o delete" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">4</th>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>9:10</td>
      <td><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa smoking">&#xf144;</i></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o delete" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">5</th>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>10:45</td>
      <td><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa smoking">&#xf144;</i></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o delete" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It seems like this can be achieved using css. There are a couple of interesting options in this stackoverflow item that could help you: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161460/how-to-set-the-index-for-a-dynamically-changing-table

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate over all the rows and update the [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property of their first cell:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.delete')).forEach((delBtn) => {
  delBtn.addEventListener('click', ({ currentTarget }) => {
    const tr = currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
    const tbody = tr.parentElement;
    
    // Hide this element:
    tr.setAttribute('hidden', true);
    
    // Update all indexes:
    let nextIndex = 0;
    
    Array.from(tbody.children).forEach((row) => {
      if (!row.hasAttribute('hidden')) {
        // Only increment the counter for those that are not hidden;
        row.children[0].textContent = ++nextIndex;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Duration</th>
      <th scope="col">Play</th>
      <th scope="col">Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Didn't love</td>
      <td>4:18</td>
      <td><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa love">&#xf144;</i></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o delete" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>                           </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Keys</td>
      <td>3:51</td>
      <td><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa keys">&#xf144;</i></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o delete" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Smoking</td>
      <td>5:12</td>
      <td><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa smoking">&#xf144;</i></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o delete" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">4</th>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>9:10</td>
      <td><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa smoking">&#xf144;</i></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o delete" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">5</th>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>10:45</td>
      <td><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa smoking">&#xf144;</i></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o delete" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Alternatively, if you actually delete the row rather than hiding it, using [`ChildNode.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove), then you could use [CSS Counters](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_counters.asp) to generate those indexes dynamically so that you don't need to update them with JS every time:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.delete')).forEach((delBtn) => {
  delBtn.addEventListener('click', ({ currentTarget }) => {
    currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.table {
  counter-reset: index;
}

.indexCell::before {
  counter-increment: index;
  content: counter(index);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Duration</th>
      <th scope="col">Play</th>
      <th scope="col">Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="indexCell"></th>
      <td>Didn't love</td>
      <td>4:18</td>
      <td><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa love">&#xf144;</i></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o delete" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>                           </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="indexCell"></th>
      <td>Keys</td>
      <td>3:51</td>
      <td><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa keys">&#xf144;</i></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o delete" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="indexCell"></th>
      <td>Smoking</td>
      <td>5:12</td>
      <td><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa smoking">&#xf144;</i></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o delete" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="indexCell"></th>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>9:10</td>
      <td><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa smoking">&#xf144;</i></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o delete" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="indexCell"></th>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>10:45</td>
      <td><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa smoking">&#xf144;</i></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o delete" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```